# server microhttpd fail to work on port 80

Tags: c++

I'm using the library libmicrohttpd ( create http program in c++ ) and
I want to run my program on the port 80.

I can run my program with the port 8080 like this :

```
daemon = MHD_start_daemon (MHD_USE_SELECT_INTERNALLY, 8080, &on_client_connect, NULL,
                             &answer_to_connection, NULL, MHD_OPTION_END);
```

but when I change to port 80, it failed and deamon is equal null.

Please have an idea?

Comment: Did you check if you already have another program listening on port 80?

Comment: Port numbers below 1024 are reserved for system use, and you usually need elevated privileges to be able to create sockets on those ports.

Comment: i check running programs with " netstat -lp --inet" and nothing is running on this port

Comment: I don't know what OS you're using (linux maybe?)
My point is, some systems require that programs using certain port ranges (port 80 included) should run in elevated mode (meaning start program using sudo). If there's no program already using port 80 like @mjuarez suggested, try using sudo or it's equivalent on whatever system you are using

Comment: Nice Joachim and T. Rex, you have the solution. I run my program in sudo mode and it works !!! Thx a lot!

Comment: Remember that running at elevated privileges is a security risk, especially running as the superuser.